# Cat,dog and human, which is most attractive for mosquito?

Tags: dogs, cats

I know some people may more attract mosquito to bite, how about cats and dogs? Is cat or dog more attract mosquitos compared with human?

Comment: Given that this seems to vary from human to human...

Comment: Not really seeing a pet connection here, seems likely that this is a better fit for the biology site since the focus of the question is on mosquitos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly genetics and varies from person to person, cat to cat, and dog to dog.  For example, my dog and I are not very attractive to mosquitoes, but my sister gets bitten all the time. It really goes by a per case for each individual and there isn't a straight answer for whether cats, dogs, or humans are the most attractive for mosquitoes.

Here is a helpful article explaining some current research on mosquitoes, humans, and pets and who/ what attracts them: [Mosquito Magnets](http://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/are-you-mosquito-magnet)